# Find ObjectId of an element inside an array of docs, that is inside a model with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have this model:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    activities: [{
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        status: String,
        from: Date,
        to: Date
    }]
}, { timestamps: true })
```

After I get the user with `User.findById()`, how can I get the `ObjectId` of an activity inside the `activities` array so I can perform (for example) `delete` and `update` operations?

**EDIT 1**
I can see every ObjectId with `console.log()` or in my GUI because MongoDB creates an ObjectId for every element inside the array even if I don't specify the field `_id` for each element. Here's a sample:

```
USER ACTIVITIES [
  {
    _id: 603765c7bb1d1c24cc7f80ff,
    description: 'Complete the project',
    status: 'pending',
    from: 2021-02-25T08:54:31.719Z,
    to: 2021-02-25T08:54:31.719Z
  },
  {
    _id: 60377672bb1d1c24cc7f8100,
    description: 'Figure out how to get the ObjectId',
    status: 'pending',
    from: 2021-02-25T10:05:38.144Z,
    to: 2021-02-25T10:05:38.144Z
  }
]
```

I'd like to access this `_id` so I can perform operations on a single activity

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a solution. In my routes file I've added one more parameter in the endpoint's path (the element ID) so I can access it via `req.params`. Then everything is simple. Here's a sample:

**Route**

```
router.delete('/activities/:id/:activityId', userController.deleteActivity);
```

**The logic**

```
exports.deleteActivity = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    if (user) {
      const activityId = req.params.activityId;
      await user.activities.pull(activityId);
      await user.save();
      console.log("ACTIVITY REMOVED! YOUR ACTIVITIES", user.activities);
      return res.status(200).json({ activities: user.activities });
    }
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "USER NOT FOUND!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error });
  }
};
```